# bcrypt error while deploying Azure Functions to Azure

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I have developed an Azure Function which ingests data from SFTP to Azure SQL database/data warehouse using Python 3.6.8. The code is built in VS code and works perfectly fine locally on my machine. When I try to deploy to function app I get below error -

> There was an error restoring dependencies. ERROR: cannot install bcrypt-3.1.6 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported.  Use the --build-ne dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish

Here is the log:

```
pip download --no-deps --only-binary :all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --python-version 36 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest ..\AppData\Local
pip download --no-deps --only-binary :all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --python-version 36 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest ..\AppData\Local
pip download --no-deps --only-binary :all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --python-version 36 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest ..AppData\Local
pip download --no-deps --only-binary :all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --python-version 36 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest ..AppData\Local
pip wheel --no-deps --no-binary :all: --wheel-dir ..AppData\Local\Temp\azureworker20z8e3i6 bcrypt==3.1.6

There was an error restoring dependencies. ERROR: cannot install bcrypt-3.1.6 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported.  Use the --build-ne dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by installing docker on my local machine and using the CLI commands to build and deploy to azure function app -

**func azure functionapp publish  --build-native-deps**